# WP-Cron function not firing

Tags: wp-cron

I am trying to get a simple php function working with cron (based on a tutorial). I have the following:

```
<?php if (!wp_next_scheduled('please_just_work')) {
 wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'please_just_work' );
}
add_action ( 'please_just_work', 'my_task_function' );
function my_task_function() { 
$test_score = 30;
update_field('score', $test_score );
} ?>
```

I can see the cron job in the Crontrol plugin, and I know that the site has to have a hit for the cron job to work, but it's just not firing. If I press "run now" from Crontrol and reload a page, it still doesn't fire. I really have no idea why:/

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Please don't abuse the php tag. I'm busy retagging all your posts. Please read the tag descriptions before using them. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your function:

```
function my_task_function() { 
    $test_score
    update_field('score', $test_score );
}
```

$test_score is not defined here, it should be $test_score = 'something'; Left the way you have it now will generate php warnings.

Also the update_field function used in this context (in a cron) will require you to pass a third argument specifying which post/page contains the field that you want to update. See the full docs on that function here: [Advanced Custom Fields: Update Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/).

Comment: Oops, my bad! Updated accordingly:) Thanks for the link, will have a read through now

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` output string into current page view. But in the case of the WP cron you *never see* that page view. It is executed asynchronously and is never sent to your browser.

You should be monitoring if it runs in some other way, for example writing a log to a file or saving something like "Last time run was..." to an option.

Comment: I updated my original question. Should that run correctly with cron? ie, update the ACF score field? (it updates correctly without cron)